# Check if an Antivirus is installed and enabled

Tags: scripting, anti-virus

I work in an entreprise with a lot of pcs > 1000 with os windows xp and 7 and symantec antivirus installed on  it
the probleme is :
-how to check if the antivirus is installed on the computers 
-and also enabled 
-then send the alert a message to the administrator

Another thing it will be best if it was vbscript

If you have ideas please share it 
Thanks very much

Comment: Use the Symantec Antivirus management console?

Comment: I was told to make a program or something like that!!

Answer (score 1):

If they are Windows XP you can do the following:

```
wmic /node:@serverlist.txt /namespace:\\root\SecurityCenter path AntiVirusProduct get /value
```

for Vista+:

```
wmic /node:@serverlist.txt /namespace:\\root\SecurityCenter2 path AntiVirusProduct get /value
```

That will run wmic against all of the servers in the serverlist.txt file

And if you need a powershell way of doing it, check here: http://blog.powershell.no/2011/06/12/use-windows-powershell-to-get-antivirus-product-information/

Here is the reference for the state of the AV product from the powershell script linked above. You can use this to make sure the AV is installed (if a server comes back with "No Instance Available"), enabled and up to date.

```
"262144" {$defstatus = "Up to date" ;$rtstatus = "Disabled"} 
"262160" {$defstatus = "Out of date" ;$rtstatus = "Disabled"} 
"266240" {$defstatus = "Up to date" ;$rtstatus = "Enabled" "Consolas">} 
"266256" {$defstatus = "Out of date" ;$rtstatus = "Enabled"} 
"393216" {$defstatus = "Up to date" ;$rtstatus = "Disabled"} 
"393232" {$defstatus = "Out of date" ;$rtstatus = "Disabled"} 
"393488" {$defstatus = "Out of date" ;$rtstatus = "Disabled"} 
"397312" {$defstatus = "Up to date" ;$rtstatus = "Enabled"} 
"397328" {$defstatus = "Out of date" ;$rtstatus = "Enabled"} 
"397584" {$defstatus = "Out of date" ;$rtstatus = "Enabled"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use group policys to set a logon script that runs a powershell script to see if the program is installed. [Powershell Reference](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/11/15/use-powershell-to-find-installed-software.aspx)

However, why are you reinventing the wheel? You could just use Symantec Antivirus Management Console...

Comment: i don't know because i think it can't be installed without a licence i just want to know if this console run automaticly without administrator intervention, in the moment he detects the problem he send a message to IT department?